From Heisenberg antiferromagnet spin coherent state path integral to the $O(3)$ sigma model with $\theta$-term
I am interested in spin coherent state path integrals. As a starting example, I want to tackle the spin-$S$ Heisenberg antiferromagnet on a line. This model is well-known to have very different physics when $S$ is integer versus half-integer, and one of the arguments is from an $O(3)$ $\sigma$-model with a $\theta$ term. For now, all I am trying to do is get to this $\sigma$ model from the spin coherent state path integral.
To emphasize: I want to be able to formally derive $\sigma$-model action from the spin coherent state path integral; I would prefer to do none of Altland and Simons' effective action derivation which heuristically argues for the non-topological piece of the action nor Haldane's derivation with semiclassical equations of motion nor Haldane and Affleck's derivation with the Hubbard model. I believe that one can directly derive the $\sigma$-model from the spin coherent state path integral; how can I do this?
My main trouble is that I can't figure out where a double-time-derivative term comes from in the action.

Here is my attempt.
The $1+1d$ fields in the spin-coherent state path integral are $\theta$ and $\phi$, although the action is sometimes written in terms of the unit vector $\vec{n}$ characterized by said angles.
As noted in Altland and Simons, the action for $J\sum_j \vec{S}_j \cdot \vec{S}_{j+1}$ is
$$\mathcal{S} = \int dt \sum_j  iS(1-\cos(\theta_j))\dot{\phi}_j + JS^2 \vec{n}_j\cdot \vec{n}_{j+1}$$
Under a change of variables $u$-substitution on the path integral measure of the form $\vec{n} \to -\vec{n}$ on the odd sublattice (equivalent to $\phi \to \phi + \pi$ and $\theta \to \pi - \theta$ on the odd sublattice). It seems natural to make a gradient expansion after this change of variables (which is like expanding about the naive classical ground state). There are probably some dangers, in that ultimately a $1$d antiferromagnet cannot order; however, this choice is made in Altland and Simons page 514. Altland and Simons do not continue the derivation directly and instead try to deduce an effective action. However, I would like to continue from this point.
This corresponds to
$$\mathcal{S} = \int dt \sum_j  iS(1-(-1)^j\cos(\theta_j))\dot{\phi}_j - \frac{JS^2}{2}\vec{n}_j\cdot \vec{n}_{j+1}$$
Let's first consider the term $\sum_j -\vec{n}_j\cdot \vec{n}_{j+1}$. Up to a constant shift, this is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\sum_j (\vec{n}_{j+1}-\vec{n}_j)^2 \sim \frac{a}{2}\int dx (\partial_x\vec{n})^2$. In the action, this becomes $\int dt \int dx \frac{JS^2a}{2}(\partial_x\vec{n})^2$.
Let's next consider the term $\sum_j (-1)^j\cos(\theta_j)\dot{\phi}_j$. I'll group the terms as $\sum_j \cos(\theta_{2j})\dot{\phi}_{2j}-\cos(\theta_{2j+1})\dot{\phi}_{2j+1} \sim \frac{1}{2}\int dx \cos(\theta) \partial_x \partial_t \phi - \sin(\theta) (\partial_x \theta)(\partial_t \phi)$. Within the action, we can integrate the first time by parts on $t$, so that the action contains a term proportional to
$\int dt \int dx \sin(\theta) (\partial_x \phi)(\partial_t \theta)  - \sin(\theta) (\partial_x \theta)(\partial_t \phi)$ plus a boundary term proportional to $\int dx \sin(\theta) \partial_x \phi\big|_{t=0}^{t=\beta}$ (I'm imagining finding the partition function, so the $t$ integrals goes from $0$ to $\beta$ with $\beta \to \infty$).
Notably, a direct computation shows that
$$\int dt \int dx \sin(\theta) ((\partial_x \phi)(\partial_t \theta)  - (\partial_x \theta)(\partial_t \phi)) = -\int dt \int dx \,\vec{n} \cdot (\partial_x \vec{n} \times \partial_t \vec{n})$$
To summarize, I get the bulk action
$$\mathcal{S}_{\rm bulk} = \int dt \int dx \left[ \frac{JS^2 a}{2} (\partial_x \vec{n})^2 +i \frac{S}{2} \vec{n} \cdot (\partial_x \vec{n} \times \partial_t \vec{n}) + i S \dot{\phi} \right]$$
plus the boundary term
$$\mathcal{S}_{\rm boundary} = \int dx \sin(\theta) \partial_x \phi\big|_{t=0}^{t=\beta}$$
I suspect but am not fully sure that this boundary term can be neglected.
The action above is tantalizingly close, but not quite the same as my desired action (which is found in Altland and Simons up to a typo $v_s \to 1/v_s$)
$$\mathcal{S}_{\rm desired} = \int dt \int dx \left[ \frac{JS^2 a}{2} (\partial_x \vec{n})^2 + \frac{1}{8 J a} (\partial_t \vec{n})^2 +i \frac{S}{2} \vec{n} \cdot (\partial_x \vec{n} \times \partial_t \vec{n}) \right]$$
which can be rescaled to have constant velocity through a change of variables on $x$ and $t$:
$$\mathcal{S}_{\rm desired} = \int dt \int dx \left[ \frac{S}{4}((\partial_x \vec{n})^2 + (\partial_t \vec{n})^2) +i \frac{S}{2} \vec{n} \cdot (\partial_x \vec{n} \times \partial_t \vec{n}) \right]$$
I'm not too concerned about the coefficients of $(\partial_x \vec{n})^2$ and $(\partial_t \vec{n})^2$ (the coefficient of $\vec{n} \cdot (\partial_x \vec{n} \times \partial_t \vec{n})$ is more important and luckily matches); rather, I'm mostly trying to figure out where any $(\partial_t \vec{n})^2$ comes from!
